How to initialise a viewmodel with an object that is being received in the view
Scenario:
You're inside a NavigationView which has a List. You select one item from the list and navigate to a detail view. This detail view needs to fetch more data based on the item you've selected in the list
ItemListView, ItemListViewModel
final class ItemListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []

    init() {
        fetchItems()
    }

    func fetchItems() -> [Item] {
        ...
    }
}


struct ItemListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ItemListViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    ItemDetailView(item: item)
                } label: {
                    ItemView(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ItemDetailView, ItemDetailViewModel
final class ItemDetailViewModel {
    @Published var itemDetail: ItemDetail

    // Want to do something like this?
    // init(itemID: String) {
    //     fetchItemDetail(itemID: self.itemID)
    // }

    
    func fetchItemDetail(itemID: String) -> ItemDetail {
        ...
    }
}

struct ItemDetailView: View {
    let item: Item
    @StateObject var viewModel: ItemDetailViewModel()

    // Can't do this
    // @StateObject var viewModel = ItemDetailViewModel(itemID: item.ID) 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }
        // I want to avoid doing this
        // .onAppear {
        //     viewModel.fetchItemDetail(itemID: item.ID)
        // }
        // .task {
        //     viewModel.fetchItemDetail(itemID: item.ID)
        // }
    }
}

What I've tried:

I have tried both .onAppear and .task, and this works as they receive the value directly in the view, but I don't like the result as a fresh call is made every time the view shows. The problem is when I navigate elsewhere and return, this call reloads.
I can't directly initialise a property in the viewmodel from the view, as naturally all properties have not yet been initialised - Cannot use instance member 'section' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available - Something like: @StateObject var viewModel = ItemDetailViewModel(itemID: item.ID)

What I want:
To be able to make this fetchItemDetail() call without reloading the view every time (I assume in the init()?) and the best practice of achieving this. Hope this makes sense!

If anything, calling fetchItemDetail in init or the property initialiser is going to get the method called more. How about just record which items have already been fetched in the view model, and don't fetch again when it is already fetched?

Does that not feel a bit hacky?

Why does it feel hacky?

Maybe just an intuitive feeling, since i'd be recording the id of the object that's already been fetched every time, I would think there's a better way to accomplish what i'm trying? This can't be a unique problem surely

If you want to keep the fetched detail objects after you leave the view you need some type of cache to hold them and the ItemDetailViewModel can’t do that since it’s recreated every time. So maybe drop that view model and only use ItemListViewModel in both views. Then this view model can either fetch data or load it from the cache depending on the situation

IMO, it's totally fine to call fetchItemDetail(itemID: item.ID) as many times. It  should be the "data provider's" responsibility to improve efficiency - i.e. utilising a cache. When using URLSession, you can easily utilise a URL cache. No hacks and no bad feelings. ;)

Did you look at the StateObject documentation they show how to create a configurable StateObject

Regarding the initialization part, You can do it in the View init body, so something like:
struct ItemDetailView: View {
    let item: Item
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ItemDetailViewModel

    init(item: Item) {
        self.item = item
        // Initialize ViewModel with correct value
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: ItemDetailViewModel(itemID: item.ID))
    }
    ...
}

Let me know if that helps.

This is error prone because the itemID supplied could change and the object will be stuck with the old item id. That's why you should use property wrappers as designed which prevents this problem.

With 1. the trick is to check if you already fetched it on the prev appear, eg:
@Environmemt(\.fetcher) var fetcher
@State var detail: ItemDetail?
let itemID: Item.ID

.task(id: itemID) {
    if detail.itemID != itemID { return } 
    detail = await fetcher.fetchItemDetail(itemID: itemID)
}

In SwiftUI the View struct hierarchy is the view model.

Well, I think the key message here is somewhat hidden: you (the OP) should not be using a separate ViewModel object in SwiftUI. The View is the view model. Adding another object that is supposed to supply the ViewModel role is going to backfire, as it does here.
